# Why snowflake jdbc throws [XX000][200001] error

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver, datagrip

I try to make connections on snowflake via datagrip and DBeaver. Test connections successfully connects on both, but it does not load the schemas and throws an error like this:

```
[XX000][200001] JDBC driver internal error: exception creating result
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeType.TİMESTAMP_LTZ at
java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:240).
```

Any solutions or faced with anyone else?

Comment: Remove the *dot* from the `I` in `TİMESTAMP_LTZ `?

Comment: Remove from where ? I just tried to make connections, I'm in the beginning phase yet. @MarmiteBomber

Comment: My point, simple delete it and *replace* it with the same `I` as us used in your comment `I just ..` (i.e. without the *dot* on it) - your `İ` has a wrong `char set` leading IMO to the problem... Scan the configuration files if you spot it.

Comment: thanks for help @MarmiteBomber the answer below solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the common bug in java programs, in your case in JDBC driver.
That caused by converting string to upper case without specifying locale, which defaults to system, which is Turkish in your case, causing `"i".toUpperCase()` to be `"İ"`.

To workaround that you could specify locale for process. In DataGrip, you can go to advanced tab of the data source settings and put `-Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en` to VM Options

[image]

Comment: Yes, the reason was because of Turkish char. This also might be the solution, but I simply changed the system language to English and it resolved.